# How to integrate the Flash Map Api on my iPhone application

Tags: ios, mapquest

i have downloaded the MQFlashMapsAPI [here](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash-mobile), it's an `.swc` file, i don't know how to get started with that exciting API in my application, can you please forward me to some useful links showing how to integrate it and how to get started in my iPhone application. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Flash Builder to "see" the [MapQuest Mobile Flash API](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/as3-flex-flash-mobile) .swc file, you have to add it to your build path.  The [Flash Builder documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-1a92eab212e75b9d8b2-7ffe.html) gives step-by-step instructions on how to do this. There is a section called "Use SWC files in your projects" about half way down the page.

As far as tutorials go, there is a good one [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/twitter-trends.html) from Adobe that might be worth a look.  It's a step-by-step tutorial that has to do with building a mobile Twitter application, but I think it's a good resource for getting started, and I intend to work through this tutorial as well when I have time.

MapQuest also has a [sample project](http://developer.mapquest.com/content/as3/v7/7.0.7_MQ_MOBILE/samples/MQMobileSample.fxp) (.fxp) that you can download as well as an [example iOS application](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mq-mobile-flash-maps-api-showcase/id467215760?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) built using the Mobile Flash API that you can get from the iTunes App Store.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems like i have to build the entire application with AIR technologies (ActionScript, Flash, etc) and then deploy it on iPhone. Well, that's not what i am ready to do for the moment, anyway, thanx for your reply my friend :)